# What is the .call() function doing in this Javascript statement?

Tags: javascript

I'm actively learning javascript, and I came across the following statement:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call([]);
```

And I don't know what it means or what it does.

I have a vague understanding of `.call`, in that it allows you to call a method in the context of a different object (I think), but I am having a hard time understanding what role the `.call()` function is playing in the above statement. So I was wondering if anyone could explain what `.call()` is doing here?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `call` method sets the `this` value of the invoked function to the object passed as first argument, in your example, you are executing the `Object.prototype.toString` method on an Array object.

Array objects, have their own `toString` method (`Array.prototype.toString`) that shadows the one from `Object.prototype`, if you call `[].toString();` the method on the `Array.prototype` will be invoked.

For example:

```
function test() {
  alert(this);
}
test.call("Hello"); // alerts "Hello"
```

Another example:

```
var alice = {
  firstName: 'Alice',
  lastName: 'Foo',
  getName: function () {
    return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
  }
};

var bob = {
  firstName: 'Bob',
  lastName: 'Bar',
};

alice.getName.call(bob); // "Bob Bar"
```

In the above example, we use the Alice's `getName` method on the Bob's object, the `this` value points to `bob`, so the method works just as if it were defined on the second object.

Now let's talk about the `Object.prototype.toString` method. All native objects in JavaScript contain an *internal property* called `[[Class]]` this property contains a string value that represents the specification defined *classification* of an object, the possible values for *native* objects are:

- `"Object"`
- `"Array"`
- `"Function"`
- `"Date"`
- `"RegExp"`
- `"String"`
- `"Number"`
- `"Boolean"`
- `"Error"` for error objects such as instances of `ReferenceError`, `TypeError`, `SyntaxError`, `Error`, etc
- `"Math"` for the global `Math` object
- `"JSON"` for the global JSON object defined on the ECMAScript 5th Ed. spec.
- `"Arguments"` for the `arguments` object (also introduced on the ES5 spec.)
- `"null"` (introduced just a couple of days ago in the [ES5 errata](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/lib/exe/fetch.php?id=es3.1%3Aes3.1_proposal_working_draft&cache=cache&media=resources:es5_errata_7-1-10.pdf))
- `"undefined"`

As I've said before that property is *internal*, there is no way to change it, the specification doesn't provide any operator or built-in function to do it, and the *only* way you can access its value is through the `Object.prototype.toString` method.

This method returns a string formed by:

```
"[object " + this.[[Class]] + "]"
```

<sub>Only for expository purposes because `[[Class]]` cannot be accessed directly.</sub>

For example:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call([]);       // "[object Array]"
Object.prototype.toString.call(/foo/);    // "[object RegExp]"
Object.prototype.toString.call({});       // "[object Object]"
Object.prototype.toString.call(new Date); // "[object Date]"
// etc...
```

This is really useful to detect the *kind* of an object in a safe way, for detecting array objects, it's the most widely used technique:

```
function isArray(obj) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) == '[object Array]';
}
```

It might be tempting to use the `instanceof` operator, but that way will lead to problems if you work on *cross-frame* environments, because an array object created on one frame, will not be `instanceof` the `Array` constructor of another.

The above method will work without any problems, because the object will contain the value of its `[[Class]]` internal property intact.

See also:

- [`instanceof` considered harmful (or how to write a robust `isArray`)](http://perfectionkills.com/instanceof-considered-harmful-or-how-to-write-a-robust-isarray/)
- [`Object.prototype.toString`](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_15.htm#Section_15.2.4.2)
- [Object Internal Properties and Methods](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_8.htm#Section_8.6.2)

Comment: +1, but that's a weird example isArray()... methods involving typeof or instanceof seem simpler.

Comment: @Jason, `typeof` is not too useful, for array objects it will just return "object", `instanceof` on the other hand works but it has problems on *cross-frame* environments (see my updated answer).

Comment: More Class types:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects

Comment: I wonder if node publishes a typescript definition with these class strings in them.  I don't see one using the IDE to explore objects like Number, Symbol or RegExp.

Answer (score 1):

Because `toString` is mostly not invoked with a parameter, not `toString('foo')`, but `bar.toString()`. Which is where `call` comes in handy.

### Different `toString`s

I say "mostly" because there are different `toString`s:

1. [`Object.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) returns a string representing object
2. [`Array.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) returns a string representing the specified array and its elements
3. [`Number.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) returns a string representing the specified Number object
4. [`String.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toString) returns a string representing the specified String object
5. [`Function.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString) returns a string representing the source code of the function

### Instance of Uses Separately

```
(new Object()).toString();                // "[object Object]"
["foo", "bar"].toString();                // "foo,bar"
(6).toString(2);                          // "110"
("meow").toString();                      // "meow"
(function(){return 'x';}).toString()      // "function (){return 'x';}"
```

Though all object prototypically inherit from `Object`, the latter ones don't inherit `toString` from `Object`'s `toString`, which means that they're all different things and have different uses. To tell the type of an object, `Object.prototype.toString` is the useful one, since it returns a type:

> Every object has a toString() method that is automatically called when the object is to be represented as a text value or when an object is referred to in a manner in which a string is expected. By default, the toString() method is inherited by every object descended from Object. If this method is not overridden in a custom object, toString() returns "[object type]", where type is the object type.

### Call

Note that among them the only one that takes parameter is `Number.prototype.toString`, and it's for specifying base of the outcome number. Therefore, in order to invoke `Object.prototype.toString` for arrays, numbers and other object that has their own toString method, you need `call` to specify `this`:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(Math);         // [object Math]
Object.prototype.toString.call(new Date);     // [object Date]
Object.prototype.toString.call(new String);   // [object String]
Object.prototype.toString.call(Math);         // [object Math]

// Since JavaScript 1.8.5
Object.prototype.toString.call(undefined);    // [object Undefined]
Object.prototype.toString.call(null);         // [object Null]
```