# Using Object.prototype.toString.call() to return object type with Javascript - not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

Hopefully I can ask this in an understandable way...

Overall, I am trying to determine what type of object I am currently dealing with.

I'm creating a collection (HTML is example, not literal) and I need to filter my collection to certain elements eg:

```
        <div id="tabContentWrap">
            <div id="tab">
                <a href="http://somelink">Link Element</a><img src="img.jpg" alt="img" />
                <select id="my_select"><option value="1">1</option></select>
            </div>
        </div>

function getFilteredElements() {
    var tabContent = getElementsByClass("tabContentWrap", document.getElementById(tabWrapId), "div");

    for (var j = 0; j < tabContent.length; j++){
        tabContentLinks = tabContent[j].getElementsByTagName('*');
        for (var k = 0; k < tabContentLinks.length; k++){
            // Here i attempt to filter the collection
            if (tabContentLinks[k] == '[object HTMLSelectElement]') {
                alert("found select list");
            }
         }
     }
 }
```

Which works fine in Mozilla but not in Internet Explorer 8, `tabContentLinks[k]` returns `[object]` instead of `[object 'ObjectType']`

So I investigated and discovered that you can use `Object.prototype.toString.call(object)` to get the object type, which again works fine in Mozilla but returns `[object Object]` in IE8...

I call

```
get_type(tabContentsLink[k]);
```

which runs the following function:

```
function get_type(thing){
    if (thing === null) return "[object Null]";
    // special case
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(thing);
}
```

But this just returns `[object Object]`

Does `Object.prototype.toString.call()` ever return the type of object in IE or am I very far off and barking up a lamppost instead of a tree?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, first of all I want to tell you that `Object.prototype.toString` returns the value of the object's internal `[[Class]]` property, it isn't really a *Type*.

The value of this internal property represents the *specification defined classification* of an object (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250379/what-is-the-call-function-doing-in-this-javascript-statement/3250415#3250415)).

Javascript has only 6 *language types*: *Object, String, Number, Boolean, Null and Undefined*, that's it.

The value of the `[[Class]]` internal property for host objects -as DOM elements- can be **anything**, it is completely *implementation-dependent*, on built-in objects is safe to use it -except with some exceptions in IE as @Alex pointed out in the article linked in his answer-.

You are working with DOM elements, and you want to figure out what kind of node it is, my suggestion to this, is to simply use the `nodeName` property <sub>(please avoid using `tagName`)</sub>.

The `nodeName` property contains the name of the node you are dealing it, in upper case, therefore you could use it as this:

```
function getFilteredElements() {
  var tabContent = getElementsByClass("tabContentWrap", 
  document.getElementById(tabWrapId), "div");

  for (var j = 0; j < tabContent.length; j++){
    tabContentLinks = tabContent[j].getElementsByTagName('*');
    for (var k = 0; k < tabContentLinks.length; k++){
      // Here i attempt to filter the collection
      if (tabContentLinks[k].nodeName == 'SELECT') { // <- SELECT elements
        alert("found select list");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Beauty in simplicity - thank you. Now I understand the differences in terminology and functionality. Great stuuf

Comment: @Alex, Thanks!, now that I see you, maybe tomorrow, I'll update my answer to [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250379/what-is-the-call-function-doing-in-this-javascript-statement), little things changed on the spec., and I will reword some parts of it :)

Comment: @dpmguise, PS: Don't forget to declare your `tabContentLinks` variable. If you just make an assignment, and the variable isn't found on the outer scope, it will become a property of the global object (an *implicit global*), moreover, this is disallowed on the new ECMAScript 5 *Strict Mode*, a `ReferenceError` exception is thrown on this kind of *undeclared assignments* -always use `var` :)...

Comment: @CMS: What's your objection to `tagName`?

Comment: @Tim: Consistency, there are some few things that I can recall, for example, `tagName` on text nodes is obviously not defined (while `nodeName` is `'#text'`). Another issue, on comment nodes, IE < 9 wrongly has `'!'` as the value of their `tagName` property (while in other browsers is not defined), and `nodeName` works consistently, having the value `'#comment'` (although I think that `nodeName` has several bugs on IE < 6).

Comment: @CMS: OK. I asked because I was not aware of any reason to use `nodeName` rather than `tagName` when you're dealing only with elements, which seeemed to be the case here.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than recreate the entire discussion and possible solutions, I'll just point you to a [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20140626150636/http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/10/cross-context-isarray-and-internet-explorer) that discusses this exact issue.

Comment: So, does that mean I have to create a circumstance for each element I wish to filter? Those (and many other) examples deal with isArray, do I have to make an isSelect and isImage functions? That's the impression I am getting...

Comment: @dpmguise in IE9 beta this is fixed. For right now, yeah, that's how I'd go about it, but there may be better ways.

Comment: @dpmguise indeed. Have..er..fun? with that. :)

Comment: Hmm, that blog post is about an specific problem, `Object.prototype.toString` with Array objects from other frames, the OP problem is regarding the fact that Host objects -as DOM elements- in IE<9 don't have defined a special value for their `[[Class]]` internal property...

Comment: @CMS do you think it's worth re-opening the question or restating it? I'll try creating the 'is' functions first

Comment: @CMS I see your point. If you have a better solution, please answer this question and I'm sure @spmguise will accept it. :)

Comment: @dpmguise, well I had some comments and recommendations about the topic, e.g. `Object.prototype.toString` doesn't really returns you the "*type*" of an object, it returns you the the value of the internal `[[Class]]` property -again, not a Type :)-, and regarding host objects, such DOM elements in your case, IMO there are better ways to achieve what you want, e.g. using `element.nodeName == 'SELECT'`, etc... if you want, I can drop an answer...

Comment: @CMS I would like you to answer this question, as I'm sure your knowledge exceeds mine and I too would like to learn what you can teach. Please share. :)

Comment: That would be great, there's not a heap out there on this I could find.... I think your element.nodeName will be my solution. Stuck on a bus at the moment, will test some code later

Comment: @dpmguise, Alex, thanks guys, I've posted an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222394/using-object-prototype-tostring-call-to-return-object-type-with-javascript-no/4222755#4222755) :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe IE will return simple data types, but everything else is just an object.  It's a browser limitation.  I don't know if IE9 is improving the situation, but that probably wouldn't help you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have IE handy, but the proper way in Firefox is to use `object.constructor.name` (`object.constructor` being the object's constructor, `.name` being the function name).

```
function Xyz() {}
new Xyz().constructor.name === 'Xyz'
```

But then, also,

```
var Abc = function() {}
new Abc().constructor.name === 'Abc'
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunatley I have tried that and I get 'undefined' in IE.