# Compare arrays as (multi-) sets

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm looking for an efficient way to find out whether two arrays contain same amounts of equal elements (in the `==` sense), in any order:

```
foo = {/*some object*/}
bar = {/*some other object*/}

a = [1,2,foo,2,bar,2]
b = [bar,2,2,2,foo,1]

sameElements(a, b) --> true
```

PS. Note that pretty much every solution in the thread uses `===` and not `==` for comparison. This is fine for my needs though.

Comment: Well, typically `foo` and `bar` will never be equal in the `==` sense, or do you want to compare they properties (deeply?) in the case of an object element?

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/comparing-two-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: @Matt: `foo` and `bar` don't have to be equal. The arrays contain both objects, `foo` and `bar`. I think that's the point (FWIW, I was confused first as well).

Comment: Use a [`Set`](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:simple_maps_and_sets) or a `Map` (with number of instances) instead of an array :-)

Comment: @thg435 
I updated the answer, i managed to optimize it a bit, giving it a performance boost of about 100%

Comment: What exactly do you want to award the bounty for? Also, please describe the average multiset components: How many primitives, how many objects are in there? How often do they occur multiple times (e.g. the objects in your example don't do at all)? It will help to get more representative performance tests and better optimized solutions.

Comment: I added the new answer, running on battery on my maching on chrome at ~100ops/s on firefox at ~80ops/s.

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4: thank you very much once again for all your helpfulness and enthusiasm!

Comment: @thg435 You are welcome :) it was a pleasure, i like stuff like this ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update 5**
I posted a new [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17229690/1487756) with a different approach.

### Update

I extended the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/Glutamat/GXVWR/1) to have the possibility of either checking by `reference` or `equality`

just pass `true` as second parameter to do a reference check.

Also I added the example to **Brunos [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/array-comparison-1/15)**

- It runs at about 11 ops/s doing a reference check

<del>**I will comment the code as soon(!) as I get some spare time to explain it a bit more, but at the moment don't have the time for that, sry**</del>. Done

Update 2.

Like Bruno pointed out in the comments `sameElements([NaN],[NaN])` yields `false`

In my opinion this is the correct behaviour as `NaN` is ambigious and should always lead to a `false` result,at least when comparing `NaN.equals(NaN)`. But he had quite a good point.

Whether

`[1,2,foo,bar,NaN,3]` should be equal to `[1,3,foo,NaN,bar,2]` or not.

Ok.. honestly I'm a bit torn whether it should or not, so i added two flags.

- Number.prototype.equal.NaN

  - If true

    - `NaN.equals(NaN) //true`
- Array.prototype.equal.NaN

  - If true

    - `[NaN].equals([NaN],true) //true`
    - *note this is only for reference checks. As a deep check would invoke `Number.prototype.equals` anyway*

Update 3:

Dang i totally missed 2 lines in the sort function.

Added

```
 r[0] = a._srt; //DANG i totally missed this line
 r[1] = b._srt; //And this.
```

Line 105 in the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Glutamat/GXVWR/1)

Which is kind of important as it determines the consistent order of the Elements.

**Update 4**
I tried to optimize the sort function a bit, and managed to get it up to about 20 ops/s.

Below is the updated code, as well as the updated fiddle =)

Also i chose to mark the objects outside the sort function, it doesn't seem to make a performance difference anymore, and its more readable

---

Here is an approach using `Object.defineProperty` to add `equals` functions to

`Array,Object,Number,String,Boolean's` `prototype` to avoid typechecking in one function for 
performance reasons. As we can recursively call `.equals` on any element.

But of course checking Objects for equality may cause performance issues in big Objects.

*So if anyone feels unpleasant manipulating native prototypes, just do a type check and put it into one function*

```
Object.defineProperty(Boolean.prototype, "equals", {
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: true,
        value: function (c) {
            return this == c; //For booleans simply return the equality
        }
    });

Object.defineProperty(Number.prototype, "equals", {
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: true,
        value: function (c) {
            if (Number.prototype.equals.NaN == true && isNaN(this) && c != c) return true; //let NaN equals NaN if flag set
            return this == c; // else do a normal compare
        }
    });

Number.prototype.equals.NaN = false; //Set to true to return true for NaN == NaN

Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "equals", {
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: true,
        value: Boolean.prototype.equals //the same (now we covered the primitives)
    });

Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "equals", {
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: true,
        value: function (c, reference) {
            if (true === reference) //If its a check by reference
                return this === c; //return the result of comparing the reference
            if (typeof this != typeof c) { 
                return false; //if the types don't match (Object equals primitive) immediately return
            }
            var d = [Object.keys(this), Object.keys(c)],//create an array with the keys of the objects, which get compared
                f = d[0].length; //store length of keys of the first obj (we need it later)
            if (f !== d[1].length) {//If the Objects differ in the length of their keys
                return false; //immediately return
            }
            for (var e = 0; e < f; e++) { //iterate over the keys of the first object
                if (d[0][e] != d[1][e] || !this[d[0][e]].equals(c[d[1][e]])) {
                    return false; //if either the key name does not match or the value does not match, return false. a call of .equal on 2 primitives simply compares them as e.g Number.prototype.equal gets called
                }
            }
            return true; //everything is equal, return true
        }
    });
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "equals", {
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: true,
        value: function (c,reference) {

            var d = this.length;
            if (d != c.length) {
                return false;
            }
            var f = Array.prototype.equals.sort(this.concat());
            c = Array.prototype.equals.sort(c.concat(),f)

            if (reference){
                for (var e = 0; e < d; e++) {
                    if (f[e] != c[e] && !(Array.prototype.equals.NaN && f[e] != f[e] && c[e] != c[e])) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }                
            } else {
                for (var e = 0; e < d; e++) {
                    if (!f[e].equals(c[e])) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;

        }
    });

Array.prototype.equals.NaN = false; //Set to true to allow [NaN].equals([NaN]) //true

Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype.equals,"sort",{
  enumerable:false,
  value:function sort (curr,prev) {
         var weight = {
            "[object Undefined]":6,         
            "[object Object]":5,
            "[object Null]":4,
            "[object String]":3,
            "[object Number]":2,
            "[object Boolean]":1
        }
        if (prev) { //mark the objects
            for (var i = prev.length,j,t;i>0;i--) {
                t = typeof (j = prev[i]);
                if (j != null && t === "object") {
                     j._pos = i;   
                } else if (t !== "object" && t != "undefined" ) break;
            }
        }

        curr.sort (sorter);

        if (prev) {
            for (var k = prev.length,l,t;k>0;k--) {
                t = typeof (l = prev[k]);
                if (t === "object" && l != null) {
                    delete l._pos;
                } else if (t !== "object" && t != "undefined" ) break;
            }
        }
        return curr;

        function sorter (a,b) {

             var tStr = Object.prototype.toString
             var types = [tStr.call(a),tStr.call(b)]
             var ret = [0,0];
             if (types[0] === types[1] && types[0] === "[object Object]") {
                 if (prev) return a._pos - b._pos
                 else {
                     return a === b ? 0 : 1;
                 }
             } else if (types [0] !== types [1]){
                     return weight[types[0]] - weight[types[1]]
             }



            return a>b?1:a<b?-1:0;
        }

    }

});
```

With this we can reduce the `sameElements` function to

```
function sameElements(c, d,referenceCheck) {
     return c.equals(d,referenceCheck);  //call .equals of Array.prototype.
}
```

*Note. of course you could put all equal functions into the `sameElements` function, for the cost of the typechecking.*

Now here are 3 examples: 1 with deep checking, 2 with reference checking.

```
var foo = {
    a: 1,
    obj: {
        number: 2,
        bool: true,
        string: "asd"
    },
    arr: [1, 2, 3]
};

var bar = {
    a: 1,
    obj: {
        number: 2,
        bool: true,
        string: "asd"
    },
    arr: [1, 2, 3]
};

var foobar = {
    a: 1,
    obj: {
        number: 2,
        bool: true,
        string: "asd"
    },
    arr: [1, 2, 3, 4]
};

var a = [1, 2, foo, 2, bar, 2];
var b = [foo, 2, 2, 2, bar, 1];
var c = [bar, 2, 2, 2, bar, 1];
```

So these are the Arrays we compare. And the output is

1. Check `a` and `b` with references only.

   `console.log (sameElements ( a,b,true)) //true As they contain the same elements`
2. Check `b` and `c` with references only

   `console.log (sameElements (b,c,true)) //false as c contains bar twice.`
3. Check `b` and `c` deeply

   `console.log (sameElements (b,c,false)) //true as bar and foo are equal but not the same`
4. Check for 2 Arrays containing NaN

   `Array.prototype.equals.NaN = true;`
   `console.log(sameElements([NaN],[NaN],true)); //true.`
   `Array.prototype.equals.NaN = false;`

**Demo on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Glutamat/GXVWR/1)**

Comment: Which runs at `8ops/s` on an `var a = JSON.parse("["+ new Array(10000).join(JSON.stringify({a:1,b:2,c:{a:3},d:[1,2,3,4]})+",") + '{}]');` 10k Array like this

Comment: Oh.. it seems I missed the point and only a reference check is needed, my bad

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what your code does. Care to explain a little more?

Comment: @thg435 Hey there =) I updated the answer, it does now either, reference or equality check. and added it to the jsperf. I'll explain it as soon as i find the time for it (i'll just comment it in here, not in the fiddle)

Comment: @thg435 I tried to explain it a little better, by commenting the code. (i'm not that good in explaining, so if there any questions left, i'll try to explain them again, just place a comment) =)

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 `sameElements( [NaN], [NaN], true )` returns false

Comment: I understand your point but according to you then what should the following call return `sameElements( [1,2,foo,2,bar,2,NaN], [bar,2,2,2,foo,1,NaN], true )`

Comment: *(deleted comment:)* I stated: Of course, as `NaN !== NaN //true` and should be... As `Not a Number` is ambigous. it would require a check in `Number.prototype.equal` -> `if (this != this && c != c) return true`

@Bruno 
Well, thats the other side. Thats a good point as well, (i deleted the comment.) And i will update the Answer with an Option in `Array.prototype.equal` to return true for `NaN` =) Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Bruno Thanks =), i updated the answer and the fiddle with flags for `[NaN].equals([NaN])` and `NaN.equals(NaN)` to yield true.

Comment: @Bruno btw, what was the change in rev 13 of the jsperf ?

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 Sorry, just wanted to see what would happen if the objects being used had a deeper structure. It turned out that your algorithm was still quicker, at least on chrome :-). If you want you can revert it back.

Comment: @Bruno Nah no need to apologize! it's your perf anyway ;) , also that's an interesting point as well, I'm totally fine with that  =) I was only curious what was changed, as i didn't want to read those 500 some lines of code. Yeah, it seems, but your codes going quite ahead on firefox

Answer (score 2):

Like this perhaps?

```
var foo = {}; var bar=[];
var a = [3,2,1,foo]; var b = [foo,1,2,3];

function comp(a,b)
{
    // immediately discard if they are of different sizes
    if (a.length != b.length) return false;

    b = b.slice(0); // clone to keep original values after the function

    a.forEach(function(e) {
        var i;
        if ((i = b.indexOf(e)) != -1)
            b.splice(i, 1);
    });

    return !b.length;
}

comp(a,b);
```

Comment: seems to work, but doesn't look particularly efficient. slice, then splice... I don't know. My arrays have 10,000's of items.

Comment: The slice is needed to clone the array. If you are not going to use it again you could remove those 2 lines... Actually you don't need to clone `a`, I will update that...

Comment: Works fine, but yours and Frédéric's solutions turned out to be quite slow for my needs.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement the following algorithm:

- If `a` and `b` do not have the same length:

  - Return `false`.
- Otherwise:

  - Clone `b`,
  - For each item in `a`:

    - If the item exists in our clone of `b`:

      - Remove the item from our clone of `b`,
    - Otherwise:

      - Return `false`.
  - Return `true`.

With Javascript 1.6, you can use [every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to write:

```
function sameElements(a, b)
{
    if (a.length != b.length) {
        return false;
    }
    var ourB = b.concat();
    return a.every(function(item) {
        var index = ourB.indexOf(item);
        if (index < 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            ourB.splice(index, 1);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Note this implementation does not completely fulfill your requirements because `indexOf()` uses strict equality (`===`) internally. If you really want non-strict equality (`==`), you will have to write an inner loop instead.

Comment: hmm, `sameElements([1,2],[1,2,3])` ??

Comment: @thg435, true, that completely escaped me. A length test is in order. I'll update my answer.

Comment: This seems to work, thanks, but see my comment to @BrunoLM: my arrays are fairly big and repeated indexOf/splice doesn't look particularly efficient. Is there a better way?

Comment: @thg435, without support for actual sets, I don't know if we can get much faster. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958292/mimicking-sets-in-javascript) explains how to emulate them, and [actual sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) are supported in Mozilla browsers.

Comment: Although quite transparent, this version turned out to be the slowest (see jsperf links in the thread).

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

As @Bergi and @thg435 point out my previous implementation was flawed so here is another implementation:

```
function sameElements(a, b) {
    var objs = [];
    // if length is not the same then must not be equal
    if (a.length != b.length) return false;

    // do an initial sort which will group types
    a.sort();
    b.sort();

    for ( var i = 0; i < a.length; i++ ) {

        var aIsPrimitive = isPrimitive(a[i]);
        var bIsPrimitive = isPrimitive(b[i]);

        // NaN will not equal itself
        if( a[i] !== a[i] ) {
            if( b[i] === b[i] ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (aIsPrimitive && bIsPrimitive) {

            if( a[i] != b[i] ) return false;
        }
        // if not primitive increment the __count property
        else if (!aIsPrimitive && !bIsPrimitive) {
            incrementCountA(a[i]);
            incrementCountB(b[i]);
            // keep track on non-primitive objects
            objs.push(i);
        }
        // if both types are not the same then this array
        // contains different number of primitives
        else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    var result = true;

    for (var i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
        var ind = objs[i];
        // if __aCount and __bCount match then object exists same
        // number of times in both arrays
        if( a[ind].__aCount !== a[ind].__bCount ) result = false;
        if( b[ind].__aCount !== b[ind].__bCount ) result = false;

        // revert object to what it was 
        // before entering this function
        delete a[ind].__aCount;
        delete a[ind].__bCount;
        delete b[ind].__aCount;
        delete b[ind].__bCount;
    }

    return result;
}

// inspired by @Bergi's code
function isPrimitive(arg) {
    return Object(arg) !== arg;
}

function incrementCountA(arg) {
    if (arg.hasOwnProperty("__aCount")) {
        arg.__aCount = arg.__aCount + 1;
    } else {
        Object.defineProperty(arg, "__aCount", {
            enumerable: false,
            value: 1,
            writable: true,
            configurable: true
        });
    }
}
function incrementCountB(arg) {
    if (arg.hasOwnProperty("__bCount")) {
        arg.__bCount = arg.__bCount + 1;
    } else {
        Object.defineProperty(arg, "__bCount", {
            enumerable: false,
            value: 1,
            writable: true,
            configurable: true
        });
    }
}
```

Then just call the function

```
sameElements( ["NaN"], [NaN] ); // false

// As "1" == 1 returns true
sameElements( [1],["1"] ); // true

sameElements( [1,2], [1,2,3] ); //false
```

The above implement actually defines a new property called "__count" that is used to keep track of non-primitive elements in both arrays. These are deleted before the function returns so as to leave the array elements as before.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/rz3Vn/14/)

jsperf [here](http://jsperf.com/array-comparison-1/11).

The reason I changed the jsperf test case was that as @Bergi states the test arrays, especially the fact there were only 2 unique objects in the whole array is not representative of what we are testing for.

One other advantage of this implementation is that if you need to make it compatible with pre IE9 browsers instead of using the defineProperty to create a non-enumerable property you could just use a normal property.

Comment: While sorting is a good idea, this fails on `sameElements([bar,bar,foo], [bar,foo,foo])`

Comment: @Bergi It does actually succeed. The reason is that although the elements are sorted, for any element which is not a primitive, which in this case foo and bar are not, the function uses `Array.indexOf` method to check that the element exists in both arrays. Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/rz3Vn/1/).

Comment: But it should return `false`…

Comment: This version indeed doesn't work correctly, but the jsperf link shows some more versions from you - consider reposting them here.

Comment: @thg435 Just updated my answer with the code I have been working on, as well as the jsPerf tests :-)

Comment: This is not working as well. Check `sameElements([o={},o], [p={},p])` which yields `true`!

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for pointing that out :( I am on a steep learning curve. Issue has been corrected now.

Comment: I added my example to the [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/array-comparison-1/12) as well. *it yields `false` for `sameElements([o={},o], [p={},p],true)`*

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for sharing ideas! I've came up with the following

```
function sameElements(a, b) {
    var hash = function(x) {
        return typeof x + (typeof x == "object" ? a.indexOf(x) : x);
    }
    return a.map(hash).sort().join() == b.map(hash).sort().join();
}
```

This isn't [the fastest](http://jsperf.com/array-comparison-1/9) solution, but IMO, most readable one so far.

Answer (score 1):

i wasn't sure if "===" is ok, the question is a bit vauge...
if so, this is quite a bit faster and simpler than some other possible ways of doing it:

```
function isSame(a,b){
  return a.length==b.length && 
      a.filter(function(a){ return b.indexOf(a)!==-1 }).length == b.length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit 2**
1) Thanks to  user2357112 for pointing out the `Object.prototype.toString.call` issue
   this also showed, the reason it was that fast, that it didn't consider Arrays ...

I fixed the code,it should be working now :), unfortunately its now at about 59ops/s on chrome and 45ops/s on ff.

*Fiddle and JSPerf is updated*.

**Edit**
1) 
 I fixed the code, it supports mutliple variables referencing the same Object now.
A little bit slower than before, but still over 100ops/s on chrome.

*2)*
I tried using a bitmask instead of an array to keep multiple positions of the objects, but its nearly 15ops/s slow

*3)* As pointed ot in the comments i forgot to reset `tmp` after `[[get]]` is called fixed the code, the fiddle, and the perf.

---

So thanks to [user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112) with his [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17182645/1487756) heres another approach using counting

```
var sameElements = (function () {
    var f, of, objectFlagName;
    of = objectFlagName = "__pos";
    var tstr = function (o) {
        var t = typeof o;
        if (o === null)
            t = "null";
        return t
    };
    var types = {};
    (function () {
        var tmp = {};
        Object.defineProperty(types, tstr(1), {
            set: function (v) {
                if (f)
                    tmp[v] = -~tmp[v];
                else
                    tmp[v] = ~-tmp[v];
            },
            get: function () {
                var ret = 1;
                for (var k in tmp) {
                    ret &= !tmp[k];
                }
                tmp = {};
                return ret;
            }
        });
    })();
    (function () {
        var tmp = {};
        Object.defineProperty(types, tstr(""), {

            set: function (v) {
                if (f) {
                    tmp[v] = -~tmp[v];
                } else {

                    tmp[v] = ~-tmp[v];
                }
            },
            get: function () {
                var ret = 1;
                for (var k in tmp) {
                    ret &= !tmp[k];
                }
                tmp = {};                
                return ret;
            }
        });
    })();

    (function () {
        var tmp = [];
        function add (v) {
            tmp.push(v);
            if (v[of]===undefined) {
                v[of] = [tmp.length -1];
            } else {
                v[of].push(tmp.length -1)
            }            

        }
        Object.defineProperty(types, tstr({}), {
            get: function () {
                var ret = true;
                for (var i = tmp.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    var c = tmp[i]
                    if (typeof c !== "undefined") {
                        ret = false
                        delete c[of]
                    }
                }
                tmp = [];
                return ret;
            },
            set: function (v) {
                var pos;
                if (f) {
                    add (v);
                } else if (!f && (pos = v[of]) !== void 0) {
                       tmp[pos.pop()] = undefined;
                       if (pos.length === 0)
                            delete v[of];
                } else {
                        add (v);
                }
            }
        });
    }());
    (function () {
        var tmp = 0;
        Object.defineProperty(types, tstr(undefined), {
            get: function () {
                var ret = !tmp;
                tmp = 0;
                return ret;

            },
            set: function () {
                tmp += f ? 1 : -1;
            }
        });
    })();
    (function () {
        var tmp = 0;
        Object.defineProperty(types, tstr(null), {
            get: function () {
                var ret = !tmp;
                tmp = 0;
                return ret;
            },
            set: function () {
                tmp += f ? 1 : -1;
            }
        });
    })();

    var tIt = [tstr(1), tstr(""), tstr({}), tstr(undefined), tstr(null)];

    return function eq(a, b) {

        f = true;
        for (var i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var v = a[i];
            types[tstr(v)] = v;
        }
        f = false;
        for (var k = b.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
            var w = b[k];
            types[tstr(w)] = w;
        }
        var r = 1;
        for (var l = 0, j; j = tIt[l]; l++) {
            r &= types [j]
        }

        return !!r;
    }
    })()
```

Here is a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Glutamat/6GPJ5/3)** and a **[JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/array-comparison-new/2)** *(it uses the same Arrays a and b as in the previous answers perf)* with this code vs the Closure [compiled](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home)

Heres the output. *note: it doesn't support a deep comparison anymore, as is*

```
var foo = {a:2}    
var bar = {a:1};
var a = [1, 2, foo, 2, bar, 2];
var b = [foo, 2, 2, 2, bar, 1];
var c = [bar, 2, 2, 2, bar, 1];
console.log(sameElements([NaN],[NaN])); //true
console.log (sameElements ( a,b))  //true
console.log (sameElements (b,c))   //false
```

Comment: added the snippet to Brunos [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/array-comparison-1/16) as well; ran out of battery can't run it

Comment: I'm currently on mobile, but I noticed in the objects type Setter , I should change the `__pos` var to be an array instead in order to support vars referencing the same object, i'll update the answer accordingly

Comment: `Object.prototype.toString.call(window) === "[object global]"` on my machine. I don't think using it is a good idea. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4222755/2357112

Comment: Also, what if you need to call this twice? All your data structures will be permanently messed up after the first call, especially if it returned false the first time.

Comment: @user2357112 Whoops i totally ment to reset `tmp` each time in the getter, thanks =) i'll fix it

Comment: There has to be a cleaner way to code this. This code could only be loved by its mother. Please refactor it :)

Comment: @Gili True that :) Thanks for pointing that out, I'll do so when I find a bit of sparse time :)

Answer (score 0):

Using efficient lookup tables for the counts of the elements:

```
function sameElements(a) { // can compare any number of arrays
    var map, maps = [], // counting booleans, numbers and strings
        nulls = [], // counting undefined and null
        nans = [], // counting nans
        objs, counts, objects = [],
        al = arguments.length;

    // quick escapes:
    if (al < 2)
        return true;
    var l0 = a.length;
    if ([].slice.call(arguments).some(function(s) { return s.length != l0; }))
        return false;

    for (var i=0; i<al; i++) {
        var multiset = arguments[i];
        maps.push(map = {}); // better: Object.create(null);
        objects.push({vals: objs=[], count: counts=[]});
        nulls[i] = 0;
        nans[i] = 0;
        for (var j=0; j<l0; j++) {
            var val = multiset[j];
            if (val !== val)
                nans[i]++;
            else if (val === null)
                nulls[i]++;
            else if (Object(val) === val) { // non-primitive
                var ind = objs.indexOf(val);
                if (ind > -1)
                    counts[ind]++;
                else
                    objs.push(val), counts.push(1);
            } else { // booleans, strings and numbers do compare together
                if (typeof val == "boolean")
                    val = +val;
                if (val in map)
                    map[val]++;
                else
                    map[val] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    // testing if nulls and nans are the same everywhere
    for (var i=1; i<al; i++)
        if (nulls[i] != nulls[0] || nans[i] != nans[0])
            return false;

    // testing if primitives were the same everywhere
    var map0 = maps[0];
    for (var el in map0)
        for (var i=1; i<al; i++) {
            if (map0[el] !== maps[i][el])
                return false;
            delete maps[i][el];
        }
    for (var i=1; i<al; i++)
        for (var el in maps[i])
            return false;

    // testing if objects were the same everywhere
    var objs0 = objects[0].vals,
        ol = objs0.length;
        counts0 = objects[0].count;
    for (var i=1; i<al; i++)
        if (objects[i].count.length != ol)
            return false;
    for (var i=0; i<ol; i++)
        for (var j=1; j<al; j++)
            if (objects[j].count[ objects[j].vals.indexOf(objs0[i]) ] != counts0[i])
                return false; 

    // else, the multisets are equal:
    return true;
}
```

It still uses `indexOf` search amongst all objects, so if you have multisets with many different objects you might want to optimize that part as well. Have a look at [Unique ID or object signature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13942209/1048572) (and it's duplicate questions) for how to get lookup table keys for them. And if you don't have many primitive values in the multisets, you might just store them in arrays and sort those before comparing each item-by-item (like @Bruno did).

Disclaimer: This solution doesn't try to get the `[[PrimitiveValue]]` of objects, they will never be counted as equal to primitives (while `==` would do).

[Here](http://jsperf.com/array-comparison-1/2) is the update on @Bruno's jsperf test of the answers, yet I guess only two objects (each of them present 500 times in the 10k array) and no duplicate primitive values are not representative.