# Sort Array B after Array A, such that references and equal Primitives, maintain the exact Position

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Update 2

I added a weight lookup to the sort function, which increased the performance by about 100% as well as the stability, as the previous sort function didn't consider all types, and as `1 == "1"` the result depends on the initial order of the Array, as @Esailija points out.

The intent of the question is to improve this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16915738/1487756) of mine, I liked the question and since it got accepted and I felt like there is some performance to squeeze out of the sort function. I asked this question here since I hadn't many clues left where to start.
 <sub>Maybe this makes things clearer as well</sub>

### Update

I rephrased the complete question, as many people stated I was not specific enough, I did my best to specify what I mean. Also, I rewrote the `sort` function to better express the intent of the question.

- Let *arrayPrev* be an *Array*  (*A*) ,where *A* consists of 0 to n *Element*s' (*E*)

  - Let an *Element* either be

    - of a *Primitive* type

      - *boolean*, *string*, *number*, *undefined*, *null*
    - a *Reference*  to an *Object*  *O*, where *O*.type = *[object Object]* and *O* can consist of

      - 0 to n *Properties*  *P*, where *P* is defined like *Element* plus

        - an circular *Reference* to any *P* in *O*
      - Where any *O* can be contained 1 to n times. In the sense of *GetReferencedName(E1) ===  GetReferencedName(E2)*...
    - a *Reference* to an *O*, where *O*.type = *[object Array]* and *O* is defined like *A*
    - a circular *Reference* to any *E* in *A*
- Let  *arrayCurr* be an *Array* of the same length as *arrayPrev*

Illustrated in the following example

```
var x = {
    a:"A Property",
    x:"24th Property",
    obj: {
        a: "A Property"
    },
    prim : 1,
}
x.obj.circ = x;

var y = {
    a:"A Property",
    x:"24th Property",
    obj: {
        a: "A Property"
    },
    prim : 1,
}
y.obj.circ = y;
var z = {};

var a = [x,x,x,null,undefined,1,y,"2",x,z]
var b = [z,x,x,y,undefined,1,null,"2",x,x]    
console.log (sort(a),sort(b,a))
```

**The Question is, how can I *efficiently* sort an *Array B*, such that any Reference to an Object or value of a Primitive, shares the *exact* same Position as in a Previously, by the *same* compareFunction, sorted, *Array A*.**

Like the above example

[image: Console Log]

Where the resulting array shall fall under the rules.

- Let *arrayPrev* contain the *Element*s' of `a` and *arrayCurr* contain the *Element*s' of `b`

  1. Let *arrayPrev* be sorted by a *CompareFunction* *C*.
  2. Let *arrayCurr* be sorted by the same *C*.

     - Let the result of sorting *arrayCur* be such, that when accessing an *E* in *arrayCur* at Position *n*, let *n* e.g be 5

       - if type of *E* is *Object* *GetReferencedName(arrayCurr[n])* === *GetReferencedName(arrayPrev[n])*
       - if type of *E* is *Primitive* *GetValue(arrayCurr[n])* === *GetValue(arrayPrev[n])*
       - i.e `b[n] === a[n]` e.g `b[5] === a[5]`
     - Meaning all *Elements* should be grouped by type, and in this sorted by value.
     - Where any call to a *Function* *F* in *C* shall be at least implemented before ES5, such that compatibility is given without the need of any shim.

My current approach is to Mark the Objects in *arrayPrev* to sort them accordingly in *arrayCurr* and later delete the Marker again. But that seems rather not that efficient.
Heres the current `sort` function used.

```
function sort3 (curr,prev) {
         var weight = {
            "[object Undefined]":6,         
            "[object Object]":5,
            "[object Null]":4,
            "[object String]":3,
            "[object Number]":2,
            "[object Boolean]":1
        }
        if (prev) { //mark the objects
            for (var i = prev.length,j,t;i>0;i--) {
                t = typeof (j = prev[i]);
                if (j != null && t === "object") {
                     j._pos = i;   
                } else if (t !== "object" && t != "undefined" ) break;
            }
        }

        curr.sort (sorter);

        if (prev) {
            for (var k = prev.length,l,t;k>0;k--) {
                t = typeof (l = prev[k]);
                if (t === "object" && l != null) {
                    delete l._pos;
                } else if (t !== "object" && t != "undefined" ) break;
            }
        }
        return curr;

        function sorter (a,b) {

             var tStr = Object.prototype.toString
             var types = [tStr.call(a),tStr.call(b)]
             var ret = [0,0];
             if (types[0] === types[1] && types[0] === "[object Object]") {
                 if (prev) return a._pos - b._pos
                 else {
                     return a === b ? 0 : 1;
                 }
             } else if (types [0] !== types [1]){
                     return weight[types[0]] - weight[types[1]]
             }



            return a>b?1:a<b?-1:0;
        }

    }
```

**Heres a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Glutamat/XmMVT/1) as well as a [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/equally-sort-array-pair/3) <sub>(feel free to add your snippet)</sub>**
 <sub>And the old [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Glutamat/cUDrA/)</sub>

Comment: what should happen incase your object has multiple keys ?

Comment: @Parthik They should have the exact same position in Array 2 as they have in Array  1. Regardless of the number , value or length of the keys.

Comment: You must state the requirement more clearly. Can the arrays contain only numbers and `Object` objects? What if it contains 2 different objects that look the same? How should circular objects compare to other objects?

Comment: @pumbaa80 thanks,  I will update the question when I'm back from mobile :)

Comment: Sorting elements of different types makes no sense in your context. Why would you have an array with `"2"`,`1`, `Object` and `undefined` in the first place? Don't abuse the dynamic nature of the language. The fact you get polymorphism for free does not mean that _logically_ array elements should not represent the same type.

Comment: This is impossible because your compare function doesn't mostly compare anything so the order is dependent on the way items are laid out in the array initially. You have to define a way to compare everything so that the result will not be dependent on the initial order of the array (except when using unstable sort algorithms but that can be made not the case).

Comment: @Esailija That's a good point! , I updated the function to sort after a type weight and the position of objects in the first array

Comment: @Benjamin I updated the question, does it make more sense in this context?

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 I'd probably use a set in an answer to that previous question. In order to sort you still need a [total order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) Which you haven't fully defined. Any answer you get before you get that ordering is basically rubbish since it makes no logical sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the arrays contain the same elements (with the same number of repetitions, possibly in a different order), then you can just copy the old array into the new one, like so:

```
function strangeSort(curr, prev) {
    curr.length = 0;             // delete the contents of curr
    curr.push.apply(curr, prev); // append the contents of prev to curr
}
```

If you don't know the arrays contain the same elements, it doesn't make sense to do what you're asking.

Judging by the thing you linked, it's likely that you're trying to *determine* whether the arrays contain the same elements. In that case, the question you're asking isn't the question you mean to ask, and a sort-based approach may not be what you want at all. Instead, I recommend a count-based algorithm.

1. Compare the lengths of the arrays. If they're different, the arrays do not contain the same elements; return false. If the lengths are equal, continue.
2. Iterate through the first array and associate each element with a count of how many times you've seen it. Now that [ES6 Maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) exist, a Map is probably the best way to track the counts. If you don't use a Map, it may be necessary or convenient to maintain counts for items of different data types differently. (If you maintain counts for objects by giving them a new property, delete the new properties before you return.)
3. Iterate through the second array. For each element,

   1. If no count is recorded for the element, return false.
   2. If the count for the element is positive, decrease it by 1.
   3. If the count for the element is 0, the element appears more times in the second array than in the first. Return false.
4. Return true.

If step 4 is reached, every item appears at least as many times in the first array as it does in the second. Otherwise, it would have been detected in step 3.1 or 3.3. If any item appeared more times in the first array than in the second, the first array would be bigger, and the algorithm would have returned in step 1. Thus, the arrays must contain the same elements with the same number of repetitions.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer, the suggestion about the comparison, i gave it a shot and it runs about 500% faster than the current. That's quite a nice improvement! =)

Comment: Will you gonna be the next Jon Skeet?

Answer (score 2):

from the description, it appears you can simply use a sort function:

```
function sortOb(a,b){a=JSON.stringify(a);b=JSON.stringify(b); return a===b?0:(a>b?1:-1);}
var x = {a:1};
var y = {a:2};

var a = [1,x,2,3,y,4,x]
var b = [1,y,3,4,x,x,2]

a.sort(sortOb);
b.sort(sortOb);
console.log (a,b);
```

Comment: JSON.stringify is rather not efficient on e.g a 10k array with objects of having nested objects. also it would fail on circular objects

Comment: you didn't show a 10k array... circular refs aside, the sheer amount of user-land code required to deeply sort is likely to cause it to run slower than the C-based JSON.stringify native routine. you can write your own caching stringifier instead of using JSON proper if the native version is too slow/fragile for your needs. im mostly trying to show the simple methodology of blackboxing the tedious details.

Comment: Well that's true, I thought that was made clear by asking for an efficient general solution , thanks for pointing that out, I''ll try to rephrase the question when I'm back from mobile :)

Answer (score 1):

Your function always returns a copy of `sort.el`, but you can have that easier:

```
var sort = (function () {
    var tmp;

    function sorter(a, b) {
        var types = [typeof a, typeof b];
        if (types[0] === "object" && types[1] === "object") {
            return tmp.indexOf(a) - tmp.indexOf(b); // sort by position in original
        }
        if (types[0] == "object") {
            return 1;
        }
        if (types[1] == "object") {
            return -1;
        }
        return a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;
    }


    return function (el) {
        if (tmp) {
            for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
                el[i] = tmp[i]; // edit el in-place, same order as tmp
            }
            return el;
        }
        tmp = [].slice.call(el); // copy original
        return tmp = el.sort(sorter); // cache result
    };

})();
```

Note that I replaced `sort.el` by `tmp` and a closure. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VLSKK/

---

Edit: This (as well as your original solution)

- only works when the arrays contain the same elements.
- maintains the order of different objects in `a`

but

- does not [mess up](http://jsfiddle.net/spRXh/) when called more than twice

Comment: Hey there, thank you for the answer =) unfortunatley, i want to avoid `Array.indexOf` if possible, As you suggested i updated the question being more specific

Comment: +1 for a this nice solution to the question, as described before the update!

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
function ComplexSort (a, b)
{
     if(typeof a == "object") { 
        a = a.a; 
    } 
    if(typeof b == "object") { 
       b = b.a;
    } 
    return a-b;
}

var x = {a:1};
var y = {a:2};

var a = [1,x,2,3,y,4,x]
var b = [1,y,3,4,x,x,2]

a.sort(ComplexSort);
b.sort(ComplexSort);
console.log ("Consistent", a,b);
```

Comment: And if my Object don't have a propertie `a` ? Thats not consistent.