# Best way to check if values of two arrays are the same/equal in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, equality

What is the best way to check if two arrays have the same/equal values (in any order) in JavaScript?

These values are just a primary keys of database entities, so they always will be different

```js
const result = [1, 3, 8, 77]
const same = [8, 3, 1, 77]
const diff = [8, 3, 5, 77]

areValuesTheSame(result, same) // true
areValuesTheSame(result, diff) // false
```

How should `areValuesTheSame` method look like?

P.S. This question looks like a duplicate but I didn't find anything relative to Javascript.

Comment: on same places or not?

Comment: not, just same values

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: not sure, they compare array [1, 2, 3] == [1, 2, 3]. I need only values [2, 3, 1] == [3, 2, 1]

Comment: Is `[0, 0]` equal to `[0]`?

Comment: Are all values numbers?

Comment: honestly, I didn't think about it, cause it is needed for database sorting, when I compare `id` of entities, they are always different

Comment: @Bergi Dude, what are you doing?

Comment: @Bergi, why it is a duplicate?

Comment: @YegorZaremba Then why not just sort both arrays and iterate over them in parallel?

Comment: @melpomene Closing as a dupe of the canonical "compare arrays for equality by their elements", did I overlook something?

Comment: @Bergi We're doing a bag comparison. Order of the elements doesn't matter. (Apparently they're also unique, so sets would work.)

Comment: @Bergi, nope, compare only values of array, place is not matter, like [1, 3, 2] === [3, 1, 2]. Your dupe its just [1, 2, 3] === [1, 2, 3]

Comment: @melpomene Ah, I see now, I only read "array" so I thought "ordered". Would [comparing ECMA6 sets for equality](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31128855/1048572) or [Compare arrays as (multi-) sets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16913668/1048572) work?

Comment: last one looks like a dupe, but answers are so old/messy, I really enjoy @ghoul-ahmed answer

Comment: @Bergi Those look good to me, but OP's actual problem is a bit more constrained, so simpler answers are possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm making the following assumptions:

- The arrays only contain numbers.
- You don't care about the order of the elements; rearranging the arrays is OK.

Under those conditions we can simply convert each array to a canonical string by sorting it and joining the elements with e.g. a space. Then (multi-)set equality boils down to simple string equality.

```js
function areValuesTheSame(a, b) {
    return a.sort().join(' ') === b.sort().join(' ');
}

const result = [1, 3, 8, 77];
const same = [8, 3, 1, 77];
const diff = [8, 3, 5, 77];

console.log(areValuesTheSame(result, same));
console.log(areValuesTheSame(result, diff));
```

This is probably the laziest / shortest approach.

Comment: @MisterJojo Yes, that's what I said (assumption #2).

Comment: your answer is so good, cause its more understandable, as someone mentioned in question, order/values place isn't matter(and it's my case), so I'll accept your solution. But @ghoul-ahmed have a nice one, too)

Comment: You could also use `JSON.stringify` instead of join, to make it also work for string or any other primitive arrays.

Comment: Pretty certain that `sort` modifies the array in place, so if you are relying on the original order of either of your arrays staying the same, this might not be the best option for you.

Answer (score 2):

You could count all elements with a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) (this is type save) up for the one array and down for the other and check if all items have a final count of zero.

```js
function haveSameValues(a, b) {
    const count = d => (m, v) => m.set(v, (m.get(v) || 0) + d)
    return Array
        .from(b.reduce(count(-1), a.reduce(count(1), new Map)).values())
        .every(v => v === 0);
}

const result = [1, 3, 8, 77]
const same = [8, 3, 1, 77]
const diff = [8, 3, 5, 77]

console.log(haveSameValues(result, same)); // true
console.log(haveSameValues(result, diff)); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const result = [1, 3, 8, 77]
const same = [8, 3, 1, 77]
const diff = [8, 3, 5, 77]
const areValuesTheSame = (a,b) => (a.length === b.length) && Object.keys(a.sort()).every(i=>a[i] === b.sort()[i])


console.log(areValuesTheSame(result, same)) // true
console.log(areValuesTheSame(result, diff)) // false
```

Comment: That doesn't work at all. If you add `9` to `same` (as in `[8, 3, 1, 77, 9]`), it still thinks it's equal to `result`.

Comment: Instead of `Object.keys()`, just use `a.sort(), b.sort().every((x, i) => x == a[i])`. Especially don't call `b.sort()` during every comparison!

Comment: @MisterJojo If order doesn't matter, it probably doesn't matter to change it. If it matters, it's trivial to clone the arrays beforehand.